# Is there a way to add a column to a view in ORACLE SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, sql-view

I have a two tables

1.TABLE_STOCK with columns
 **Product_ID**(primary key) and **Product_unit_price**

2.TABLE_SALES with columns **Product_ID**(foreign key) and **Sales_unit_price**

Now I wanted to create a **view** joining the two tables based on Product_ID and add a column **PROFIT**(which should be the difference between Sales_unit_price and Product_unit_price) to the view.

Is there a way to add a column(PROFIT) to a view?

Comment: On a side note: I think it's a bad idea to create a table called `table_stock` and call its primary key column `product_id`. Table name and key column should match as in `create table product(product_id number(14), name varchar2(100), price number(5,2), stock number(6);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as the way you've already described.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_PRODUCT
AS
   SELECT K.PRODUCT_ID,
      K.PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE,
      S.SALES_UNIT_PRICE,
      S.SALES_UNIT_PRICE - K.PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE AS PROFIT
 FROM TABLE_STOCK K
      INNER JOIN TABLE_SALES S ON S.PRODUCT_ID = K.PRODUCT_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Now how do I order the result based on Profit in descending and Product_ID in Ascending?

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY` clause at the end of your query. ORDER BY S.SALES_UNIT_PRICE - K.PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE DESC, K.PRODUCT_ID ASC

Comment: @Udaysai Muthyala: A view, just like a table, is unordered. You can use `ORDER BY` in the queries you are using this view in, e.g. `select * from v_product order by profit desc;`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have stock with no sales (but presumably not sales without some stock).  Hence, I think you need an `outer join`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_PRODUCT AS
   SELECT st.PRODUCT_ID, st.PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE,
          s.SALES_UNIT_PRICE,
          (s.SALES_UNIT_PRICE - K.PRODUCT_UNIT_PRICE) AS PROFIT
   FROM TABLE_STOCK st LEFT JOIN
        TABLE_SALES s
        ON S.PRODUCT_ID = st.PRODUCT_ID;
```

You may need a `FULL JOIN`, if you can have sales with no stock.